# Show Dialog in non-activity class 1x/day

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-context

I want an alertdialog to show up on my Android app once a day at a specific time. I created a class with a thread running checking the OS time, once the times match, I want to show an alertdialog at whatever activity the user is on. I attempted to pass the current context and the current activity but neither work as the dialog does not show up. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Here are 2 of the functions in my nonactivity class.

```
void start_time_thread() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Looper.prepare();
            while (true) {
                int currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //Current hour
                if (currentHour > hour || currentHour < hour) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current Hour: " + currentHour + " reminder hour: " + hour);
                } else {
                    int currentMin = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE); //Current min
                    if ((min - 1) == currentMin) {
                        showWarningAlert(CURRENT_CONTEXT);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
 private void showWarningAlert(Activity activity) { //Added current activity
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create(); //Use activity
        alertDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Reminder msg");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to work either with :

1- Work manager
2- Alarm Manager

to achieve show the dialog on specific time to user because android system kills background service for battery optimization